# How to use image type in hibernate?

Tags: image, hibernate, myeclipse

I am using myeclipse to reverse engineer from ms sql server to hibernate.
and I found when there are a column with the type 'image' in database, after I reverse engineer the table, the 'image' column was converted to 'String' in table definition. So actually what can I do to handle the 'image' type well with hibernate ? What type should I use in my class ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out:
[Java Type VS Hibernate Type](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Hibernate/JavaTypeVSHibernateType.htm)

Image type could be represented by binary, CLOB or BLOB equivalent types for SQL Server database, so in Hibernate.

Check [this MySQL example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-save-image-into-database/) also, and this specific info on [binary types on MSSQL](http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/a/binary.htm), which will serve to develop by analogy the process you need.

Comment: Do u mean I should manually map the image type to serializable type in hibernate ?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-save-image-into-database/, this website is really good, thanks for sharing!